Moving graph nodes relative to how zoomed in you are
I'm using a tool called ReactFlow/Svelteflow to place nodes on a 2D graph. Right now, I'm working on copy-paste functionality.
These graphs have the concept of "zoom". You can zoom in and out of the graph.
I'd like to be able to copy nodes while zoomed in a certain amount, change the zoom level and then paste the nodes and have them end up in the same relative position within the viewport.
Here are the variables I have to work with:

Viewport at time of copy: (x, y, zoom) Viewport at time of paste: (x,
y, zoom) Point coordinates: (x, y)

Dividing x and y by the zoom level gives you the absolute coordinates of the points.
So far, as long as I don't alter the zoom level, this equation works:
xDiff = newViewport.x / newViewport.zoom - oldViewport.x / oldViewport.zoom;
yDiff = newViewport.y / newViewport.zoom - oldViewport.y / oldViewport.zoom;
point.x = point.x - xDiff;
point.y = point.y - yDiff;

This works only if I don't alter the zoom level. If I copy, zoom out, and then try to paste, the point is far off towards the top left. If I copy, zoom in, and then paste, the point is far off towards to bottom right.
EDIT:
I've also tried this:
xDiff = newViewport.x / newViewport.zoom - oldViewport.x / oldViewport.zoom;
yDiff = newViewport.y / newViewport.zoom - oldViewport.y / oldViewport.zoom;
scaleDiff = clonedCopyData.viewport.zoom / viewport.zoom;
point.x = point.x * scaleDiff - xDiff;
point.y = point.y * scaleDiff- yDiff;

and I think that's more of what I'm looking for. In fact, this may be my answer. But if anyone else has a better solution, I'd love to hear.
